# Sharing localStorage between web app and extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a "Notifications" system which, with user permission, pops up a `new Notification` complete with optional sound effect to inform users of things happening.

However there is a limitation that means that notifications won't appear when there are no browser tabs open, since there are no instances of the "check for notifications" JavaScript code running.

To remedy this, I want to make a browser extension, first for Chrome and then potentially for other browsers.

Multiple tabs are already handled by using `localStorage` to negotiate mutexes and pass data across tabs. The result is that they all update simultaneously and only one of them triggers the desktop notification / sound effect.

Is it possible for the browser extension (again, Chrome first, other browsers are considered less important for this) to read from the same `localStorage` as the web app, and thereby join in the communications?

Comment: Should I expect answer by you in next few mins?

Comment: @Tushar Heh, no. This is an actual question XD

Comment: For Chrome and Firefox, your backend can send [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en), so that notifications can be received even if the sites tab isn't open (but browser must be). [MDN's Using Push API article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the browser extension (again, Chrome first, other browsers are considered less important for this) to read from the same localStorage as the web app, and thereby join in the communications?

Yes, but only while the page is open. A content script will share its `localStorage` with the page, and there is no API to access it otherwise.

---

That said, I agree with the comment from Patrick Evans: an extension is a cumbersome solution ONLY for notifications. The new Push API is a great alternative (also works on mobile!), and this [Google codelab](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/) is a great introduction.